# Negative order of accuracy

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, computational-mathematics

Suppose we analyze the order of accuracy of a finite difference approximation of a derivative,

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2h} \left[f(x-2h) -4f(x-h) +3f(x)\right]$$

and we conclude that the order of accuracy is 1 because our analysis would indicate that there is one $O(h)$ term.

Now, what if instead of the above formula we tried to analyze

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2h} \left[f(x-2h) -4f(x-h) +4f(x)\right]$$

Then our analysis would give us an additional (to $O(h)$) term, $\frac{f(x)}{2h}$, or $O(h^{-1})$.

What would this signify in terms of the order of accuracy?

Comment: That it's not a very sensible approximation?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I was thinking this too, but I'm wondering if there's a negative order of approximation in theory.

Comment: @sequence: Wouldn't every approximation of order p have an approximation order of -p if $h \mapsto 1/h$? It's not useful, but it meets your criteria.